# How could I understand the concept of topological phase transitions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, thermodynamics, classical-mechanics

I'm a freshman and don't have much knowledge about condensed matter theory, but I'm really interested in the concept of topological phase transitions; could someone explain it in a popular way?

Comment: Did you check Wikipedia before asking here about a so broad concept ? If you have an access to a library, perhaps you can also try reading the introduction and first chapter of the Sachdev's book Quantum phase transition (somehow a synonym for *topological phase transition*). Otherwise, in short : a topological phase transition is the change of the ground state when a system present several degenerate ground states. Said differently, this is the tunnelling between two macroscopically available states for a macroscopic body at equilibrium (= at zero temperature if you wish).

Comment: @FraSchelle Thanks a lot for answering my question(to be honest,I look for Wikipedia but don't quite understood it)Maybe I shall look for some books in library ^_^

Comment: I just gave you a few keywords you may try to understand (ground state, tunnelling, quantum phase transition, phase transition, ...) , feel free to insist on this question and related extra ones. As it is, your question is pretty broad, and perhaps no-one will spend time to answer it, but if you can cut it in smaller questions, then you will get some answers. At least I hope so for you.

Comment: Note my previous answer is only partially true (I'm not an expert on the field) : a system with many different ground states is not necessarily in a topological phase, but the reverse is true: a system in a topological phase must have several degenerate ground states. Then the topological phase is the ground state the system is in, and the topological phase transition is the change of ground state.

Comment: @FraSchelle Yeah,you are right.I gonna look for some small piece of it first.and thanks again~